# Como enviar un mensaje FCM desde php a dispositivos Androir

Tags: php, android, firebase-messaging

estoy haciendo mi primera aplicación Android con flutter. Quiero enviar notificaciones a todos los usuarios cuando alguien reporte un problema, para lo cual estoy tratando de usar firebase.

Ya he creado mi aplicación en firebase y la he conectado a mi aplicación android. He probado enviar un mensaje desde la consola colocando en la segmentación solamente el id de mi aplicación.

Ahora lo que quiero es poder hacer lo mismo desde php. Toda la información que he encontrado sobre el tema habla de enviar mensajes por tópico o a un dispositivo en particular (usando un token que no tengo idea de cómo obtenerlo).

Intenté con este código (lo agrego al final), pero me da "InvalidRegistration", porque en el parámetro to: le estaba pasando lo que en la cónsola ponía como segmento.

```
<?php
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$token = "lo usado en el panel de firebase como segmento";

$serverKey = 'AAAAHVx--pk:APA91...........................................sORXPduGEwqA6Yr8nfsdquOGiF0FyoGTYGO-aYoisuUdDlG1punE';

$title = "Prueba desde php";

$body = "Hola, soy tu amable servidor";

$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'body' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');

$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
//Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//Close request
if ($response === FALSE) {
die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

?>

Comment: [Aquí tienes un tutorial completo](http://www.androiddeft.com/push-notification-android-firebase-php/#Sending_notifications_using_PHP) para empezar. La API key te la da Google en la [consola de desarrolladores](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Comment: correcto, ese tutorial ya lo había leído y me parece bastante bueno y completo. Mi duda es porque ahí habla de enviar el mensaje a un dispositivo puntual, o a un tópico. Lo que yo quería era enviar el mensaje a cualquier dispositivo que haya instalado mi app.Entonces asumo que esas dos son las únicas opciones y lo que debo hacer es elegir entre guardar los tokens de todos los dispositivos en mi base de datos para poder enviar el mensaje, o inscribir automáticamente mi app en un tópico para hacerlo según ese método, ¿estoy en lo correcto?